# PJSUA crash on Android after getting Ringing response from server

Tags: android, asterisk, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm sending some additional info within contact header to server in REGISTER reuqest, and everything goes normal, but when i try to handle incoming call - application crashes with no error in log just after sending RINGING response.

Here is my **register** message:

```
REGISTER sip:8022@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj2ec0a45d-ed19-
4638-82fd-fd99c0c0ec2a
Route: <sip:8022@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5060;lr>
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:XXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX>;tag=f11614bc-65b3-4742-846a-f36b207b27ad
To: <sip:8022@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX>
Call-ID: 708c9a3b-be50-4c45-b49c-ac6843547ad0
CSeq: 59316 REGISTER
User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.6
Contact: <sip:XXXX@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5060;app-id=my.app;pn-type=android;pn-
tok=<token_string_here>;ob>
Expires: 300
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, 
REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Authorization: Digest username="8022", realm="asterisk", 
nonce="1495458128/d947e48afff90d90490a665850fde439", 
uri="sip:8022@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", response="291fbdfd407ba19d3d916ec28a88e1a2", 
algorithm=md5, cnonce="e55f14a6-95f3-4ace-a4cb-a24cdf4f2bdc", 
opaque="0c274aee613c50ab", qop=auth, nc=00000001
Content-Length:  0
--end msg--
```

Additional stuff like app-id, pn-type, pn-tok was added via

```
accCfg.getSipConfig().setContactUriParams(myContactParams);
```

When INVITE request comes, PJSUA sends TRYING response(SIP status 100), then 
I send RINGING status(180) response to INVITE.

Here is my **RINGING** response:

```
Response msg 180/INVITE/cseq=6662 (tdta0xac62c838) to TCP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:52891:
SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5060;rport=52891;received=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;branch=z9hG4bKPje30b530e-e7f3-4404-b937-61d8046a43f8;alias
Call-ID: 43da8440-9a30-49ed-8345-17a2e515c590
From: <sip:8003@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX>;tag=4b2008cd-14db-4edc-97f5-c5fde8ffccb8
To: <sip:8022@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;app-id=my.app;pn-type=android;pn-tok=<token_string_here>;ob>;tag=fd58966e-ef74-48f6-9595-542d85f1e87d
CSeq: 6662 INVITE
Contact: <sip:8022@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5060;app-id=my.app;pn-type=android;pn-tok=<token_string_here>;ob>
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0
--end msg--
```

Then i've got two more lines in logcat from PJSUA

```
I/PJSUA2: 16:46:22.408  tsx0xac3c3f7c  ....State changed from Proceeding to Proceeding, event=TX_MSG
I/PJSUA2: 16:46:22.408  dlg0xac479014  .....Transaction tsx0xac3c3f7c state changed to Proceeding
```

and the app immediately crashes with no any PJSUA messages in log.

And yes, everything work perfectly without any additional info in contact header.

Is there any ways to solve this problem?
If there is a restriction from PJSIP - can i change it by setting some flag before compile or maybe there is another way to send additional contact info in REGISTER request?

We using Huawei P8 Lite (Android 6.0) with Android Studio 2.3.2, PJSIP v2.6 compiled for Android, Asterisk PJSIP 13, but the error happens at Aterisk 11 too.

Comment: Is the `To`- and `From`-URI in the SIP REGISTER the same? The should be equal unless you're performing third party registrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was about token length in contact.

I've workaround this by sending token using our REST API.
I'm didn't go too deep in subject, seems like it's a exceeding MTU size while sending sip message over UDP. As soon as i don't need TCP transport in my project, i haven't tested sending that message by TCP.

In case someone still ineterested, here is a link at pjsip.org about msg size and some tips about how to reduce it:

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/FAQ#sip-msg-size

Comment: If anyone still interesting for it, PJSIP guys are close to release pjsip 2.7, and seems like they fixed something about long contact in pjsua (from 2.7. milestones: pjsua2, swig:
#2021
Crash in getting call info with long Contact header)